# Undefined Method 'add_product ' for model object

Tags: methods, undefined, ruby-on-rails-4.2

[image]I think my error is kind of silly, but it's keeping me stuck. I'm following the Agile Web Development with Rails 4 and developing the app Depot from it. I'm getting a

```
undefined method `add_product' for #<Cart:0x007f2ee4cfb8f8>
```

error. My code is as follows,

```
class LineItemsController < ApplicationController

def create
    find_cart
    product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
    byebug
    @line_item = @cart.add_product(product.id) // line with error
    @line_item.product = product
    respond_to do |format|
        if @line_item.save
            format.html {redirect_to @line_item.cart, 
                            notice: 'Line Item was succesfully created'}
            format.json {render json: @line_item,
                            status: :created, location: @line_item}
        else
            format.html {render action: "new"}
            format.json {render json: @line_item.errors,
                        status: "Unprocessable Entry"}
        end
    end
end
end
```

Cart.rb

```
class Cart < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :line_items, dependent: :destroy

def add_products(product_id)
    current_item = line_items.find_by_product_id(product_id)
    if current_item
        current_item.qunatity += 1
    else
        current_item = line_items.build(product_id: product_id)
    end
    current_item
end
end
```

Also, I want to know, how can a method from different model be directly called into a separate controller ?
The object cart has value, I have debugged to make sure, as well as the error line also has the object present.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the mistake, it was a typo I made in Cart.rb. I had named the method add_product's' and was calling add_product in the controller.